# Matrix operations in openCV

Tags: c, opencv

I'm using OpenCV in C as a image processing tool in my latest project for performance reasons . While using Open CV , I found out that  Open CV has less library support for matrix operations . For example if wanted to add a column vector to every column in a matrix , I will have to write a custom function to do this . There are many more operations that seemed trivial in Matlab, missing in Open CV - like norm of each column , column wise min/max etc .In short all Column wise operations on a matrix seems to be missing in Open CV (I would be surprised if I didn't find more).The matrix manipulation support for library is very minimal. Is this a design decision for the library or is there some sort of an extension that can help me through this . I believe there must have been others who observed and did something about the lack of support.Any pointers ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenCV may not be a complete replacement for MatLab, but its matrix support is still quite good. You may find that some of the features you are looking for are there but simply have different names.

> For example if wanted to add a column vector to every column in a matrix , I will have to write a custom function to do this.

You can do this a few ways; probably the easiest is with ranges. See below for one solution.

> like norm of each column

Use a matrix range to select each column in a loop:

```
cv::Mat m;

// ...

for (unsigned c = 0; c < m.cols(); c++)
{
    cv::Mat col(m, cv::Range::all(), cv::Range(c, c+1));
    double n = cv::norm(col, NORM_L2);
}
```

> column wise min/max etc

The `cv::reduce` function provides all these sorts of features:

```
cv::reduce(InputArray src, OutputArray dst, int dim, int rtype);
// where rtype = CV_REDUCE_MIN, CV_REDUCE_MAX, etc
```

> In short all Column wise operations on a matrix seems to be missing in Open CV (I would be surprised if I didn't find more).

`cv::reduce()` also performs sum and average. You can choose to perform column-wise or row-wise.  If these operations aren't sufficient for your needs, you may actually have to write your own functions.

The online documentation is pretty good:

- [OpenCV Core Reference](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/core.html)

The tutorial has more info on memory management and matrices, in particular explaining about ranges and how this can share memory:

- [OpenCV Tutorial: Mat - The Basic Image Container](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/mat_the_basic_image_container/mat_the_basic_image_container.html)

Comment: I'm writing code in C , not C++ so that i can port to embedded platform . Do you have pointers to C documentation . Your answer still  gives me an idea how to approach the problem .Thank you

Comment: The C API corresponds to OpenCV 1.x, while 2.x is the migration toward C++. Some APIs still exist in C, so often you can just take the namespace and concatenate it with the function name, so (for example) take `cv::reduce`, giving `cvReduce`. But in general, C++ (or Python) is the way to go, and the docs will list all the bindings which are supported in the refs above. Which platform are you targeting? Most have C++ support these days anyway.

Comment: @Malice If you insist on using the legacy API, you don't really have a right to complain about the lack of functionality. Go to http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/old_basic_structures.html and then look up the C functions in the index. Of course OpenCV with C++ can be ported to many embedded platforms, which is a capability you won't get with Matlab.

Comment: @B . I'm pretty weak in objected oriented languages and is more familiar with C . I'm doing this on an intel atom architecture . Since this is a hard deadline realtime project ,the efficiency in C would  help me a lot in case the processing take too much time

Comment: @Malice You can certainly develop in C++ for the Atom architecture - without loss of efficiency. And there's no reason you can't develop your image processing routines using OpenCV in C++ and wrap them in a plain C API, and use C for the rest of your project.